# Looping through and adding to an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to add multiple teams to an array by looping through and finding the teams with my players id. I'm only getting the last team that is connected with my player. what did I do wrong.

```
@players = @user.players
@team = Team.all
@players.each do |player|
  @t = @team.find(player.team_id)
  @teams = Array.new
  @teams.push(@t)
end
```

Comment: I don't know ruby so this is a guess, but it looks like you're recreating the array each time

Answer (score 1):

Instantiate the array outside the loop.  As you have it, `@teams = Array.new` will create a new `@teams` array on each iteration.

```
@players = @user.players
@team = Team.all
@teams = Array.new
@players.each do |player|
  @t = @team.find(player.team_id)
  @teams.push(@t)
end
```